# Html.fromHtml within Gmail Sender .sendMail(string, string, string, string)

Tags: android, html, parameters, gmail, html-email

I have the following code:

```
dev = "email@gmail.com";
dev_p = "password";
subject = "Thank you for signing up to the company auditing app";
body = "<!DOCTYPE html><body>To " + username + ",\nThank you for signing up to the company auditing application.\nYou can login to your account via our website <a href='http://www.companyauditingapp.com/'>here</a>.\n Regards,\nThe Team</body></html>";
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(body);
try{
    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(dev, dev_p);
    sender.sendMail(subject,html,dev,emailadd);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

I want to be able to send html via the sendMail method, in eclipse it keeps asking me to change the method parameter - strings html/body to a spanned string.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: The second parameter should be of String type instead of Spanned.

Comment: Im trying to add html into my email, display html in the email that I am sending, do I need to change the method parameters or add headers to the email?

Comment: Try to replace the method call like this `sender.sendMail(subject, body, dev, emailadd)`. Use the `body` variable instead of `html`. Then it will either work or have a different error.

Comment: yes but then that would throw the whole "String" of tags through to the sendMail method. All I am trying to do is send the string into the method, so that at the other end the email is viewed in HTML.

Comment: You should send a string and set some header which switches text/html. I don't know where you got your `GMailSender` class, but if it is taken from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/427225, you can replace `text/plain` by `text/html` in the `sendMail` method.

Comment: i think that is exactly what i was looking for, yet to change and test, but i couldnt find it! ta

Comment: @vorrtex if you want to put that in an answer i'd be happy to accept it as the answer, so it was basically changing text/plain to text/html, ta once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has turned out that `GMailSender` is a custom class published by a stackoverflow user in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/427225).

The easiest way to send HTML instead of plain text is to change the `sendMail` method from the link above and replace `text/plain` by `text/html`.

Or you can add a parameter to the method and make it more customizable:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients, boolean isHtml) throws Exception {   
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        String messageType = isHtml ? "text/html" : "text/plain";
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), messageType));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want HTML-messages, you can change the sendmail function and change `text/plain` to `text/html`.

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), **"text/plain"**));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e)
    }
}
```

Comment: The sendMail function is located in the public class GMailSender.